# How to manually retrieve license file for license MATLAB

Tags: matlab, installation

Supposing you already have the license key associated with your MathWorks account, where do you find the license file?

[image]

And the instructions says

> License File Processing on Server
>
> When you install the license manager, the installer performs the
>   following processing of this License File:
>
> - Makes a copy of your License File, naming it license.dat, and puts this copy in the \etc folder of your MATLAB installation folder.
> - Adds a SERVER line and a DAEMON line to the file. The SERVER line identifies the server (host and port number). The DAEMON line
>     identifies the name of the license manager daemon.

But there is no \etc folder and there is no license.dat. I checked my MATLAB folder in Program Files. What I did is directly download MATLAB from the website with my account.

UPDATE:

I used the network.lic as the license file and MATLAB accepted it. Then installation was finished so it instructed me to restart my computer. I restarted my computer and tried activating it again. Because it prompted me to activate it again. It made me undergo the same steps until this popped out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You buy the license. It is a text file and can be placed anywhere on the computer that later during the installation you point to it.

Comment: Uhm, I actually have a license for this. From my university. They just emailed me the license key and associated it to my email.

Comment: You don't need the license manager. That's for companies that want to authenticate matlab users. You are reading the wrong instructions. You download the license file from your MathWorks account when you log on through MathWorks. Failing that, you can authenticate directly online when you run matlab the first time. No need for a license file.

Comment: @rayryeng I edited my question kindly check the last image

Comment: Sorry. Not sure. Please contact MathWorks. .